# Omega theme on Ipad slides across and disappears

Tags: theming

I'm using the latest Omega 3 theme on my drupal 7.32 site caerleonlodgehillprimary.org. I notice on the ipad2 (also Ipad Mini), if you swipe across to the left, the entire page disappears and you are left with a blank page. Has anyone got any ideas why that is? I was wondering whether its some kind of corruption in the footer, the last thing I added was to add a Contact Us block showing the address and email in the footer (which is a View based on the Contact Us node), I noticed in portrait mode, the email spills over into the next block. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by my social icons in the footer, the same problem is referred to in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004707/responsive-website-on-iphone-unwanted-white-space-on-rotate-from-landscape-to) posting, it occurs when a DIV gets too big for the page, the Ipad cant cope with this and creates a load of space on the right of your page. In my case, I have an text indent -999 in the class of my social button, defined as :-

```
.social-button{

    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-indent: -999em;
    display: inline-block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    margin-right: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
```

}

To resolve I put :-

```
width:auto; 
overflow-x:hidden;
```

on the css for the social icons Block in the footer and it worked perfectly as suggested in the link above. Sorry this is slightly off topic with a CSS resolution, but I though it would save someone (like me) hours of messing around with their theme to find a problem thats not there . Thanks